# I'm looking for how to recreate a similar chart in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn, tableau-api

I'm looking for a way to create a graph like this but in Python where it's like a stacked bar chart but each segment is in it's own column. This was created in Tableau with the aggregate and one dimension in the columns section and the other variable as rows. I've been looking for awhile to no avail, any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You can create a similar graph using `barh` subplots with shared y-axes.

Answer (score 1):

You can get something similar to your picture using
*df.style.bar*, e.g.:

```
df.style.bar(subset=['Col_1', 'Col_2', 'Col_3', 'Col_4', 'Col_5'],
    width=75, vmin=0, color='lightgreen')
```

For a few initial rows from your sample I got the following
result:

[image]

Search the Web for documentation of this function and experiment
with changes in its parameters.